# Redmi 9A stuck at logo bootloop, can't access fastboot

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking, xiaomi, redmi

I was trying to flash the fresh port of Ubuntu Touch to my Redmi 9A, an error occurred in the middle of the installation and now I'm stuck at the Redmi logo bootloop and can't access fastboot. ADB also doesn't recognize the phone anymore. How would I go on about flashing/accessing fastboot? The bootloader was unlocked with the official MI Unlock Tool, no problems. Also I don't care about recovering any files whatsoever since it's all backed up. Any input would be much appreciated!

I've got a Linux and a Windows machine if it makes a difference for the software needed to proceed.